# insg1 = Insegnante.from_string(iron_man, "Ingegneria") AttributeError: type object 'Insegnante' has no attribute 'from_string'

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class Insegnante(Persona):
profilo = "Insegnante"
def __init__(self, nome, cognome, età, residenza, materie=None):
    super().__init__(nome, cognome, età, residenza)
    if materie is None:
        self.materie = []
    else:
        self.materie = materie

def scheda_personale(self):
    scheda = f"""
    Profilo: {Insegnante.profilo}
    Materie: {self.materie}"""
    return super().scheda_personale() + scheda
    
def aggiungi_materia(self,nuova):
    if nuova not in self.materie:
        self.materie.append(nuova)
    print("Elenco materie aggiornato")
```

When I try to use it like so:

```
  insg1 = Insegnante.from_string(iron_man, "Ingegneria")
```

I get this error:

```
 insg1 = Insegnante.from_string(iron_man, "Ingegneria")
 AttributeError: type object 'Insegnante' has no attribute 'from_string'
```

What is wrong with the code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `insg1 = Insegnante.from_string(iron_man, "Ingegneria")`, *what do you think that should do*? **Why** should it do that? Where, in the code that you show us, is the part of the code that you expect to be used in order to get that result? Please read [ask] and [mre], and show your reasoning.

Comment: I [edit]ed the post to show how to ask a question directly and avoid [noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721). Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; writing things like "help me pls" is not helpful and only distracts from the **question**. There is still a lot more that needs to be fixed here, in order to have a proper question. Please start by reading the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); make sure the code appears indented as you actually have it.

Comment: Next, make sure we can test your example directly. It should be possible to **copy and paste** your code **without changing anything**, and **directly** see the problem you are asking about. We cannot do this here, because for example there is no definition for `iron_man`. On the other hand, please *remove* things that are *not relevant* to the problem. For example, if `Insegnante` does not have a `scheda_personale`, will the example still work the same way? (Do you *need to use* `scheda_personale` in order to cause the problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call the `from_string` method of the `Insegnante` class, but this class has no method `from_string`.

you can implement it yourself:

```
class Insegnante(Persona):
    profilo = "Insegnante"
    def __init__(self, nome, cognome, età, residenza, materie=None):
        super().__init__(nome, cognome, età, residenza)
        if materie is None:
            self.materie = []
        else:
            self.materie = materie

    def scheda_personale(self):
        scheda = f"""
        Profilo: {Insegnante.profilo}
        Materie: {self.materie}"""
        return super().scheda_personale() + scheda
        
    def aggiungi_materia(self,nuova):
        if nuova not in self.materie:
            self.materie.append(nuova)
        print("Elenco materie aggiornato")

    def from_string(param1, param2):
        # build your Insegante object and return it
        return ...
```

Comment: It should be a `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` (with an added `cls` parameter) if OP wants to call it in the way described. Also, it's not very helpful to say only this much because *we have no idea what that method should do*. I assume it's intended to construct an instance of the class; but who knows what the rules are for determining the `nome`, `cognome`, `età`, and `residenza` to use, and who even knows what type `iron_man` has?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree that the problem is not clearly stated, I wrote the most general method implementation not to interfere too much

Comment: I'll delete my answer after OP's edit